# Get history of a project in Visual Source Safe 2005

Tags: report, visual-sourcesafe

I would like to get a report of the changes made to all the files in a project. I know how to do it for a single file, but I don't know how to do it recursively. Have you tried to do something similar? Is there a specific tool to accomplish this task? Thank you.

Comment: [Check this link](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2009/08/sometimes-it-is-really-useful-to-be.html), it tells you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS6.0 but is should be similar.

- Right click on the source safe directory (project) and choose "Show history"
- In the options dialog check "recursive"
- You get a history dialog. In the history dialog you press "report" and in the report dialog you check "include details".

Comment: Strange. For me if I check "include details" I get the user, date/time, and comment for every check in. Maybe they changed it in 2005.